# How can i pass form loop values in ajax and get by php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which contain radio buttons, which is in a loop. If the loop has 10 count, it will show ten set of radio buttons. I have a structure like below, so I need to get all the values and insert in the database.

**HTML:**

```
     <form id="sendForm">
         <?php
             $n = 0;
             for ($x=0; $x < count($q_id); $x++)
             {   
         ?>
             How is our Services?
             <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>"  id="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>" value="poor"/>
             </label>

             <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>"  id="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>" value="Bad"/>
             </label>

             <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>"  id="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>" value="Good"/>
             </label>

             <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>"  id="Choice_<?php echo $n;?>" value="VeryGood"/>
             </label>
         <?php
                 $n = $n+1;
             }
         ?> 
     </form>
```

Here is how validation happen:

**JavaScript:**

```
   var names = [];
   $('input:radio').each(function () {
       var rname = $(this).attr('name');
       if ($.inArray(rname, names) == -1) names.push(rname);
   });

   //do validation for each group
   $.each(names, function (i, name) {
       if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length == 0) {
           $("#Error").after('<span class="error">Choose the above field</span>');
           valid=false;
       }
   });

   if(valid)
   {
       SubmitForm();
   }

   return valid;
```

**Ajax:**

```
   function SubmitForm() {
       var formdata = $('#sendForm').serialize(); 

       $.ajax({             
           type: 'POST',
           url : '/post_page.php',
           data: formdata,
           async: false
       }).done(function(msg) 
       { 
           //Success or error
       }
   }
```

I got stuck now how to get each values of radio buttons selected and get by $_POST[] and save in database.

Comment: what can you see if you print ` $_POST`?

Comment: This is not good way to do this. You should defined form element's name with array bracket notation. How your table structure look like?